# Dailymotion regex bbcode tinymce

Tags: javascript, regex, tinymce-4, bbcode

I'm using tinymce bbcode plugin, and i have following code to replace dailymotion video to bbcode:

```
 rep(/<iframe.*?src=\"(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?(?:\/\/www\.)?
     (dailymotion\.com|dai\.ly)\/((video\/([^_]+))|(hub\/([^_]+)|([^\/_]+)))\
     ".*?width=\"(.*?)\".*?height=\"(.*?)\".*?><\/iframe>/gi,
     "[dailymotion width=$2 height=$3]$1[/dailymotion]");
```

Tinyce output iframe video:

```
<iframe src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x5iscr6" width="480" height="270"></iframe>
```

My regex code doesn't work, i need help.

Comment: iframe have extra "embed" that break your regex. I don't know is it optional or mandatory parameter, I added it here as mandatory:
https://regex101.com/r/lRtcAM/1

Comment: yes i forget for embed, thank you for help!